# Calling generic method with generic interface as parameter with reflection causes ArgumentException

Tags: c#, generics, expression

Let's say that I have the following interface:

```
public interface IInterface<out T> {
    T Instance { get; set; }
}
```

and a method inside a class:

```
public void DoSomething<T>(IInterface<T> @object) { ... }
```

Now I want to call `DoSomething` with an object of type `IInterface<Foo>` with Expression inside this class.

So I have a method inside the same class:

```
public void FooBar() {
    object methodGeneric = ...;
    Type genericType = methodGeneric.GetType(); // of type Foo

    object o = ...;
    Type t = o.GetType(); // of type IInterface<Foo>
    MethodInfo m = GetType().GetMethod("DoSomething").MakeGenericMethod(genericType));

    var param = Expression.Parameter(t, "o");
    var cast = Expression.Convert(param, typeof(object));
    var @this = Expression.Constant(this);
    var call = Expression.Call(@this, m, cast); // here's where the exception occurs.
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<object>>(call, param).Compile();
    lambda(o);
}
```

The exception that then occurs is the following:

```
Expression of type 'System.Object' cannot be used for parameter of type 'IInterface' of method 'void DoSomething[Foo](IInterface[Foo])'
```

I've tried to use Expression.TypeAs instead of convert resulting with the same exception.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: It would help if you could provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: My *guess* is that `Expression.Convert(param, typeof(object))` should be `Expression.Convert(param, t)`. Or perhaps use `typeof(IInterface<>).MakeGenericType(genericType)` instead of `t`. After all, you do want to provide an `IInterface<Foo>`, right?

Comment: The problem here is that I want to call the lambda function with an object.
That's why I want to convert the param to typeof(object) in the first place :)

Comment: You can call it with the code I've given so long as the *execution-time* type is appropriate, I believe.